# Calculate fan power

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, pipelines

**I was wondering how to calculate the required fan power for the following air pipe network.** Other losses besides friction is not calculated for.

[image: Pipe network]

Known parameters:

- Fan provided flow, **VA = 3000 m3/h**
- pressure at inlet to fan and outlets 1,2,3 , **1 bar**
- Friction coefficient, **f = 0.012**
- Lenghts, **L1 = 20m**, **L2 = 5m**, **L3 = 20m**, **LA = 50m**, **LB = 5m**
- Density of air, constant at **1.2 kg/m3** (we are assuming incompressible flow)
- Pipe diameter, **d = 0.25m** (same for all)
- Output flow, $\dot V_1=0.3128$ m3/s, $\dot V_2=0.3470$ m3/s, $\dot V_3=0.1735$ m3/s
- Fan efficency, ${\eta _f} = 0.75$

With the known parameters I could formulate the equation for the fan power:
$$\left| {{{\dot E}_f}} \right| = {\dot V_A} \cdot \frac{{\Delta p}}{{{\eta _f}}}$$

**I am unsure how to define the pressure increase ${\Delta p}$ from the fan**

I have tried defining it as the sum of all pipe's pressure loss using the following:
**$$\frac{{\Delta {p_{f,i}}}}{\rho } = f \cdot w_i^2 \cdot \frac{{{L_i}}}{d}$$**

That however did not yield an appropriate answer.